# Problema visualización perfiles en página principal

Tags: bug, estado-por-diseño

Des de la página principal de [stackoverflow en español](https://es.stackoverflow.com/) veo mi inicio así:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Cómo podéis ver no se ven bien los perfiles de las persones que pregunten (cómo sí que sen ven en cualquier otra página):

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: creo que es más un tema de formato que un problema. Si visitas SO en inglés ocurre igual, pinchas en preguntas y tiene un formato, pinchas en el Logo y tiene otro. Creo que es solo eso.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Hasta donde tengo entendido, la primera vista es propia de la página inicial y está así por diseño de la aplicación. Sucede lo mismo en cualquier otro sitio de StackExchange. Además, cabe resaltar que la primera vista que muestras denota al usuario que ha realizado la última actividad en dicha publicación pregunta/respuesta/comentario mientras que la vista de Preguntas siempre muestra al usuario autor de la pregunta con el uso del mini perfil.

Comment: Exacto. La vista de "Preguntas principales" está diseñada para ser compacta, algo así como el equivalente a un feed RSS. Fijaos que tampoco aparece el texto de la pregunta en esa vista, sólo el título.